# How to add UIImageView (UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage) in SDWebImage downloader?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage for image downloading. I want show a indicator while downloading the image. I got a class UIImageView (`UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage`) for that. Actually i have got it from : [Github link](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage). Any one please help me how I add it in my project. I am not using cocoapod. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the .h and the .m in your project as said in the documentation

In the first error the UIImageView+WebCache category is not found. Are you sure you have imported SDWebImage? Also it seems from the second screenshot that SDWebImageCompletionBlock is not found. I think this was introduced in version 3.7 of SDWebImage, so maybe you have an old version

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have got a error. please check http://tinyurl.com/nkc34l7. Then I have changed the code Then also I have got a error. plz check: http://tinyurl.com/pd4x7fq